# Connecting R to postgreSQL database

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I am trying to connect R to a postgreSQL database. He is what I have been trying in R:

```
require("RPostgreSQL")

pw<- {
  "password"
}

# loads the PostgreSQL driver
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
# creates a connection to the postgres database
# note that "con" will be used later in each connection to the database
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "DBname",
                 host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                 user = "user", password = pw)
rm(pw) # removes the password

# check for the test_table
dbExistsTable(con, "test_table")
# FALSE >>> Should be true
```

I cannot figure out why it is not properly connecting to my database. I know that the database is on my computer as I can connect to it in the terminal and with pgAdmin4. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do you need port 5436?

Comment: What do you get when you `dbListTables(con)`

Comment: So that does give me my tables. Looks like the connection is working. I am not sure why it keeps giving me a false answer. I should have tried a query first before asking a question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: on the side note, you can put your secrets to .Renviron file and load them with `Sys.getenv`.

Comment: Does *test_table* output with `dbListTables()` as @vagabond suggests? Do note: Postgres is case-sensitive.

Comment: Off topic but see also dplyr https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html ... the syntax is much easier than sql for complex joins and long queries

Answer (score 11):

I have had better success with the `RPostgres` package in combination with `DBI` and I know that `RPostgreSQL` just released a new version in May after no changes for a while. `RPostgres` is pretty active

```
## install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("RcppCore/Rcpp")
#devtools::install_github("rstats-db/DBI")
#devtools::install_github("rstats-db/RPostgres")

library(RPostgres)
library(DBI)

pw<- {
  "password"
}

con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres()
     , host='localhost'
     , port='5432'
     , dbname='DBname'
     , user='user'
     , password=pw)


rm(pw) # removes the password

dbExistsTable(con, "test_table")
```

Answer (score 9):

```
install.packages("RPostgreSQL")
require("RPostgreSQL")
# this completes installing packages

# now start creating connection
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
                 dbname = "dbname",
                 host = "localhost",
                 port = 5432,
                 user = "db_user",
                 password = "db_password")
# this completes creating connection

# get all the tables from connection
dbListTables(con)
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue could be table permission

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_table TO user`

Replace `your_table` and `user` with your own credentials

You can get `table` from `\dt` and `user` from `\du`